# Верно ли, что в данном предложении есть лишняя запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обороты-с-как

Мне кажется, что третья запятая лишняя (первые две обосабливают сравнительный оборот, а для третьей просто нет обоснования). Так ли это?

*В окружении матросов с обгоревшими, как под палящим солнцем, руками(,) он чувствовал себя не в своей тарелке.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь скорее не хватает еще одной запятой:

*В окружении матросов, **с обгоревшими, как под палящим солнцем, руками**, он чувствовал себя не в своей тарелке.*

Обособляется несогласованное распространенное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного.

Оно обозначает **не отличительный признак** определяемого существительного, а **дополнительное описание**. В общем случае распространенность и осложнение несогласованного определения увеличивает вероятность  его обособления.

В то же время необособленный вариант также возможен, тогда третья запятая действительно лишняя. Авторский выбор делается по контексту.